# How to clear text inputs if user selects "Please Select" option from drop down menu?

Tags: php, jquery, html

Below I have a drop down menu:

```
 $courseHTML = '';

.... //sql code to perform query goes here

    $courseHTML = '<select name="courses" id="coursesDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
    $courseHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;           

    $courseInfo = array();

    while ( $courseqrystmt->fetch() ) {

    $courseHTML .= sprintf("<option value='%s'>%s - %s</option>", $dbCourseId,$dbCourseNo,$dbCourseName) . PHP_EOL; 

    $courseData = array();
    $courseData["CourseId"] = $dbCourseId;
    $courseData["CourseNo"] = $dbCourseNo;
    $courseData["CourseName"] = $dbCourseName;
    $courseData["Duration"] = $dbDuration;

    array_push($courseInfo, $courseData);
    }


    $courseHTML .= '</select>';
```

Below is the html table where it will display the current details of the course in table:

```
$editcourse = "
<form id='updateCourseForm'>

    <p><strong>Current Course Details:</strong></p>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td><input type='hidden' id='currentCourseId' name='CourseIdcurrent' value='' /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Course ID:</th>
    <td><input type='text' id='currentCourseNo' name='CourseNocurrent' readonly='readonly' value='' /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Course Name:</th>
    <td><input type='text' id='currentCourseName' name='CourseNamecurrent' readonly='readonly' value='' /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Duration (Years):</th>
    <td><input type='text' id='currentDuration' name='Durationcurrent' readonly='readonly' value=''/> </td>
    </tr>
    </table>    
    </form>

";
```

I have a jquery code below where it displays the details in the text inputs above depending on the option selected from the drop down menu. It fills the text input with the details no problem. But what my problem is that what is suppose to happen is that if the user selects the "Please Select" option in the drop down menu, then all the text inputs should be empty. Problem is that it is still displaying the information in the text input wven though I am on the "PLease Select" option.

What do I need to change in code below in order to be able to blank out the text inputs if "Please Select" option is chosen from drop down menu?

```
$(document).ready( function(){

var courseinfo = <?php echo json_encode($courseInfo);?>;


        $('#coursesDrop').change( function(){

            var courseId = $(this).val(),
            coursedata;

        for (var i = 0, l = courseinfo.length; i < l; i++)
        {
                if (courseinfo[i].CourseId == courseId) { 
                    coursedata = courseinfo[i]; 
                    }
        }

        var currentindex = $('#currentDuration').val(coursedata.Duration);
        var editindex = $('#newDuration').val(coursedata.Duration);
        var currentid = $('#currentCourseId').val(coursedata.CourseId);
        var editid = $('#newCourseId').val(coursedata.CourseId);

            if( $(this).val() !== '' ){
                var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
                var split = text.split(' - ');
                $('#currentCourseNo').val( split[0] );     
                $('#currentCourseName').val( split[1] );       
            }
            else{
                $('#currentCourseNo,#currentCourseName,#currentDuration,#currentCourseId').val('');           
            }
        });
        });
```

Comment: Try `.remove(0)` instead of `.val('')`

Comment: @RogerNg Do you mean change ` if( $(this).val() !== '' ){
` to ` if( $(this).remove(0)!== '' ){`? If so I have done this and all it does is remove the drop down menu itself

Comment: Are you sure there are no JS errors? simple example works http://jsbin.com/aqepom/1

Comment: @sachleen Aha, there is an error, the error is displayed in the error console when I select the "PLease" select option again, the error states that coursedata is undefined on this line `        var currentindex = $('#currentDuration').val(coursedata.Duration);` But how come its undefined coz I stated it in jquery code

Comment: courseId is blank when you select "please select" so the if condition is never met inside the for loop, and so `coursedata` is never set.

Comment: @sachleen Ok so in your answer can you show what I need to include in the code please so I can look at your code and make the change and then I can mark your answer and learn from your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem:

> there is an error, the error is displayed in the error console when I
>   select the "PLease" select option again, the error states that
>   coursedata is undefined on this line `var currentindex =
>   $('#currentDuration').val(coursedata.Duration);`

Explanation:

> courseId is blank when you select "please select" so the if condition
>   is never met inside the for loop, and so coursedata is never set.

Solution:

Check for a valid (not "Please Select...") selection first, then do the work. I've also reorganized some other parts of the JS so it makes more sense.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var courseinfo = <? php echo json_encode($courseInfo); ?> ;

    $('#coursesDrop').change(function () {
        var courseId = $(this).val();

        /*
            You only need to do all of this if user selects a course, so check that first.
        */
        if (courseId !== '') {
            /*
                Iterate over courses and, if the one we want exists, populate its info.
            */
            for (var i = 0, l = courseinfo.length; i < l; i++) {
                if (courseinfo[i].CourseId == courseId) {
                    $('#currentDuration').val(courseinfo[i].Duration);
                    $('#newDuration').val(courseinfo[i].Duration);
                    $('#currentCourseId').val(courseinfo[i].CourseId);
                    $('#newCourseId').val(courseinfo[i].CourseId);

                    var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
                    var split = text.split(' - ');
                    $('#currentCourseNo').val(split[0]);
                    $('#currentCourseName').val(split[1]);

                    /*
                        Without this break, the loop will continue until i = l.
                        We've already found our match, no need to continue.
                    */
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $('#currentCourseNo,#currentCourseName,#currentDuration,#currentCourseId').val('');
        }
    });
});
```